# Obtaining longitude/latitude by method other than navigator.geolocation?

Tags: javascript, geocode

Are there any other methods besides using `navigator.geolocation` to get access to a user's longitude and latitude location in JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than using Ajax to get data from an external service that approximates it based on the IP address the request came from, which is an indirect method, no.

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to use a geo IP location service, try freegeoip.net. It is a free (public) service maintained by community donations.  You get 10,000 lookups per hour.

My job is in Vancouver, WA and when I used the service with the IP of my workstation, I got the right result (freegeoip.net/xml/):


- 216.65.151.102 US United States WA Washington Vancouver  * removed by me   removed by me * 820 360 

If you don't mind paying, MaxMind offers a really good service at $20 per 10,000 lookups.

http://www.maxmind.com/en/web_services